# Auto-update data on fragment from API service in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-volley

I am working on an application that makes request to API to update user dashboard. At the moment the data is only being called when user logs in at first but whenever the user moves to other fragment to carry out transaction and comes back to the dashboard, it(the dashboard) shows the placeholder information and user can only get updated information by logging out and relog-in.

I had thought of using shared preference but still having my doubt about its security or persistency

How can I implement a situation where data will remain persistent whenever user comes back to the dashboard?

Comment: When you do a mutation on your data, the backend should send you the new values. That way you would not need to know what API to call again in order to get the new values.

Comment: yes but how do I make the backend do this?

Comment: Well if you are writing the backend, it's as simple as returning the modified values in the response. If you are NOT responsible for the backend.. then I guess you can code that "if you called this method, then you should invoke this API request to get a fresh version of this data".